# MySQL - Parallel merge two unrelated queries with same # of rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

**exam_outline_items:**

[image: Query Table One]

**jml_quiz_pool:**

[image: Query Table Two]

Of all the things I've tried, this got me the closest:

```
select t1.sequence, t1.title, t2.q_cat, t2.q_count
from student_pl.exam_outline_items t1
cross join pe_joomla.jml_quiz_pool t2
where t1.exam_outline_id = 5 and t1.chapter_num > 0
    and t2.q_id = 1109 and t2.q_count > 0
group by title
```

Which produces this result:

[image: Query Results from 3rd query]

I just need those q_cat values to be different, like they are in the 2nd query.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: And how do you determine, which sequence and title belongs to which q_cat and q_count?

Comment: They will match perfectly in parallel as long as the queries are run as described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have something to connect them with. If you don't have such a column, you can simulate one by creating a rownumber with variables.

```
select sequence, title, q_cat, q_count from (
    select t1.sequence, t1.title, @r1 := @r1 + 1 as rownumber
    from student_pl.exam_outline_items t1
    , (select @r1 := 0) var_init
    where t1.exam_outline_id = 5 and t1.chapter_num > 0
    order by t1.sequence
) a
inner join
(
    select t2.q_cat, t2.q_count, @r2 := @r2 + 1 as rownumber
    from pe_joomla.jml_quiz_pool t2
    , (select @r2 := 0) var_init
    where t2.q_id = 1109 and t2.q_count > 0
    order by t2.q_cat
) b on a.rownumber = b.rownumber;
```

Also note, that I used `order by` in those queries. In a database you have no sort order unless you explicitly set it with `order by`.