# Select multiple columns in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I dont know if it's the right question.

I have a table with two fields, credit and debit.
I make a sum of each field and then create a new column with the total balance.
I created several query that work well separately
Is this:

```
SELECT Sum(libromayor.debe) AS IngresosGlobal,
Sum(libromayor.haber) AS GastosGlobal,           
(Sum(libromayor.debe) - Sum(libromayor.haber)) AS TotalGlobal
FROM libromayor
```

and this:

```
SELECT Sum(libromayor.debe) AS IngresosActual,
Sum(libromayor.haber) AS GastosActual,
(Sum(libromayor.debe) - Sum(libromayor.haber)) AS TotalActual
FROM libromayor
WHERE Year(libromayor.fechaevento) = Year(CurDate())
```

what I would like is to unite the two queries, but leaving the result in this case in 6 columns, not 3 as in this query attempt:

```
SELECT Sum(libromayor.debe) AS IngresosGlobal,
Sum(libromayor.haber) AS GastosGlobal,           
(Sum(libromayor.debe) - Sum(libromayor.haber)) AS TotalGlobal
FROM libromayor
UNION 
SELECT Sum(libromayor.debe) AS IngresosActual,
Sum(libromayor.haber) AS GastosActual,
(Sum(libromayor.debe) - Sum(libromayor.haber)) AS TotalActual
FROM libromayor
WHERE Year(libromayor.fechaevento) = Year(CurDate())
```

the result given is this:

```
IngresosGlobal   GastosGlobal   TotalGlobal
1521.00            1575.00        -54.00
121.00              100.00         21.00
```

but I would like to create a VIEW that give this result

```
IngresosGlobal   GastosGlobal   TotalGlobal     IngresosActual     GastosActual     TotalActual
1521.00            1575.00        -54.00           121.00              100.00           21.00
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786079/mysql-parallel-merge-two-unrelated-queries-with-same-of-rows

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT Sum(libromayor.debe) AS IngresosGlobal,
sum(IF(ear(libromayor.fechaevento) = Year(CurDate()), libromayor.debe, 0)) AS IngresosGlobal2
FROM libromayor
```

P.S. showing just on one column, to give you idea